# laravel validation error on large file upload

Tags: laravel

```
{
    "status": false,
    "message": "The member id field is required.",
    "code": 422,
    "errors": {
        "member_id": [
            "The member id field is required."
        ],
        "type": [
            "The type field is required."
        ],
        "filename": [
            "The filename field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: None of the errors are about filesize? How are you sure it's caused by the filesize?

Comment: It works perfectly fine on localhost . but it sends validation error or nginx server .

Comment: I think you can increase the size in `nginx.conf` file

Comment: how are you uploading the file? Make sure you are using a multi-part request

Comment: i have added  client_max_body_size 200M  on nginx . but it stil does not work .

Comment: when the file exceeds php max post size, the input is truncated, the other fields never reach the server and a validation error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

If you sure the error is because of file size be sure to update `php.ini` settings with correct numbers, eg:

```
post_max_size = 200M
upload_max_filesize = 200M
variables_order = EGPCS
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you are editing the wrong file. Because under php folder, there are many php.ini files such as cgi, cli, and fpm folders.
You should add it to the php.ini of the fpm folder.

Add these in php.ini

```
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
```

And then restart the nginx service

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx.service
```